# How to calculate ln(2^2048)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

All the calculators I've tried overflow at 2^1024. I'm not sure how to go about calculating this number and potentially even larger ones.

Comment: Hint. $\ln(a^b) = b \ln(a)$.

Comment: Good thing there is more to math than just calculators..

Comment: The lovely Windows 7 calculator (trashed thereafter) reports `3.231700607131100730071487668867e+616`

Comment: ... and it reports for $\ln(2^{2048 })$ `1419.5654257867679936864913847463`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the property $\ln(2^{2048})=2048\cdot \ln(2)$. Hence the answer is approximately $2048\cdot 0,693=1419.264$.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $$2048\cdot \ln(2)$$ which is equal to $\ln(2^{2048})$